# How do I make a thruster in Unity 2d?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a 2d game in Unity and I can't find how to make a thruster. I have a rotating character and I need to apply a force 90 to my characters angle.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Can you please include your attempts? Also please specify what a "thruster" is

Comment: I have no attempts because I have no idea how to make it. a thruster is a device which outputs a force at a certain angle, like in a spacecraft, or jetpack. I need to apply a force on my character, that force's angle depends on the characters angle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all of the help, the command I was searching for was [Rigidbody2D.AddForceAtPosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.AddForceAtPosition.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use the [RigidBody](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.html) system in Unity with the .AddForce(); calls.

For example:

```
myRigidBody.AddForce(transform.forward);
```

Comment: How do I apply that force opposing to a character's angle?

Comment: @chimado [`AddRelativeForce`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.AddRelativeForce.html) will translate the provided `Vector2` to be relative to the rigid body's local coordinate system. This will allow you to use `Vector2.up`, `Vector2.down`, `Vector2.right`, or `Vector2.left` without having to think too much about the rotation of the object and then rotating your force vector accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`RigidBody2D.AddRelativeForce`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.AddRelativeForce.html) to achieve this. It will apply a force in a constant direction that is relative to the `gameObject`, meaning that it will always apply to the right or left of your character, no matter which way it is rotated. Try `rb.AddRelativeForce(Vector2.right)` to add force that makes your character go to the right, or `rb.AddRelativeForce(Vector2.right * -1)` to make it go to the left.

Hope this helps!